# How to acquire Sabre's WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, sabre

Does anyone have an idea how to get WSDL of SOAP services by Sabre (https://developer.sabre.com/)? I'm totally stuck with it.

Comment: Under https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/SOAP_APIs links to individual WSDL schemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are an existing Sabre Web Services customer consuming SOAP Services, these will be enabled under Resources link on the Documentation page for each SOAP API Page.

If you are looking to get access to SOAP Services, please contact Sabre on Sabre Dev Studio for more information on getting access to these.

developer.sabre.com

Comment: I log in, but none of Resources pages are available. Does it mean I am supposed to get some sort of subscription in order to access them?

Comment: If you are an existing Sabre Web Services SOAP developer, did you provide your PCC when registering? Select the option to Contact Sabre on Dev Studio and provide this information.

Comment: No, I just went to Sabre Dev Studio and clicked "register". How do I become Sabre Web Services SOAP developer and get PCC?

Comment: Please contact Sabre from here:
https://developer.sabre.com/contact